# Watermark to appear on canvas after submit

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, submit, watermark

I have a HTML canvas, you choose a color and a size for the circle and when onclick, the circle appears. Now I want a watermark with the text "Hello" to be seen before you paint the circles and then disappear when you start drawing and the canvas goes back to just being white. 
I also has a submit button that that removes all the circles, and I want the watermark to appear when the button is clicked.
I'm sorry for my bad English, but I hope you'll understand my question.

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ez56zat5/2/).

**Javascript**

```
function initiateCanvasCircle() {
var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    input = document.getElementById( 'myColor' ),
    size = document.getElementById( 'mySize' ),
    watermark = document.getElementById( 'myWatermark' );
context.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop;

});

context.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, size.value / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);


    context.fillStyle = input.value ? '#' + input.value : '#333';

    context.fill();
});

}

function circle() {
    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        initiateCanvasCircle();
    });
}

function drawCircle() {
    circle();
}

initiateCanvasCircle();



// Button   
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, false);
  myCanvas.addEventListener('click', function() { }, false);
```

I really hope you can help me to understand how to make a watermark act the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some little changes to your [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ez56zat5/3/)

Added these 2 functions to add text and clear the canvas:

```
function drawText() {
     var x = canvas.width / 2;
     var y = canvas.height / 2;

      context.font = '30pt Calibri';
      context.textAlign = 'center';
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillText('Hello World!', x, y);   
}

function clearCanvas(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawnOnCanvas = false;
}
```

And some other changes to onClick, added variable drawnOnCanvas to keep track when the text needs to appear etc.

Comment: That's great! Thank you for your answer! If I want the canvas to be white instead of the grey backgrund I have now, what do I have to do then?

Comment: In de `clearCanvas()` function after `clearRect()` add: `context.fillStyle="white";
context.fill();`

Comment: Doesn't work :(  function clearCanvas(){
    context.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ); 
 context.fillStyle="white"; context.fill();
    drawnOnCanvas = false;
}

Comment: But it still isn't white (green) in the beginning... just when you click and when you clear

Comment: Just add `clearCanvas();` below "// Button" and above `drawText();`

Comment: Thank you! I ran in to another problem with my code now :( If you type in a wrong value in the boxes, for example #0000000 the program doesn't do anything, but if I want to add a alert box, how would I do that? The same for the size, you can't, for example, type in abc.

Comment: You would need to detect when someone entered wrong values, maybe onChange or something. And then a boolean "canDraw" or so